# Point context from an external txt file to a List

Tags: python, list

So, i have a .txt file labeled numbers.txt that contains the numbers:

```
56
4
-23
45
```

and is currently sitting say under `C:\numbers.txt`

I wrote this which works just fine to return the mean:

```
def mean(M):
    # Return mean
    return sum(M)/len(M)

def test_for_importing_txt_to_list():
    test_list = [56, 4, -23, 45]

    mean_total = mean(test_list)
    print (mean_total)

test_for_importing_txt_to_list()
```

What I'll like to know is how to have an empty list point to the `C:\numbers.txt` containing those same numbers without me having to have any entries on the list itself.
So when i run the program, it gives me the mean of what ever numbers are included on the `numbers.txt` file itself?

I read some doc on reading files as 'filename.txt','r' and writing as 'filename','w'
But - not quite working for me yet.

Answer (score 0):

You could [open the file](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) with `open('C:\numbers.txt', 'r')`. 
Since the file object returned by `open` is an iterator that returns lines from the file, you could then use [`map(int, ...)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) to convert each line into an `int`:

```
def test_for_importing_txt_to_list():
    test_list = map(int, open('C:\numbers.txt', 'r'))
    mean_total = mean(test_list)
    print (mean_total)
```